# Suitecrm Database schema for multiple companies

Tags: sugarcrm

How can I separate database using suitecrm.

In My application there is one source code and i want to company wise separate database.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use seperate installations for keeping them seperate.

Additionally, you can use $sugar_config['db'] variable to dynamically connect with a database of your choice.